# Vue not rendering child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I get this error trying to rendering a Vue test code on the browser:

[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: custom-input If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.

custom-input is the child component I created.

```
app.component('custom-input ', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <label> 
        {{ label }}
        <input type="text" />  
      </label>
    </div>
  `,
  props: ['label']
})
```

It's parent is login-form.

```
app.component('login-form', {
  template: `
  <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit"> 
      <h1> {{ title }} </h1>
      <custom-input type="email" v-bind:label="emailLabel" /> 
      <custom-input type="password" v-bind:label="passwordLabel" />
      <button>Log in</button>
    </form>  
  </div>
  `,
  components: ['custom-input'],
  data () {
    return {
      title: "Login Form",
      email: '',
      password: '',
      emailLabel: 'Email',
      passwordLabel: 'Password',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleSubmit() {
      console.log(this.email + "\n" + this.password)
    }
  }
})
```

As you can see, I'm using the custom-input tag twice in the login-form component, but I get the error I mentioned before, and they do not render, I just get the rest of the login-form template HTML code.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNewP.png)

The error says that I got to exclude the custom component from the component resolution, so I added the line of code:

```
app.config.compilerOptions.isCustomElement = (tag) => tag.includes('custom-input');
```

But then I got the same result but without the warning message.

Comment: You don't need to re-declare a global component, either declare it as global and forget it in `components` or include it without making it global. And yes, once it's global, you can just use it in the template without declaring it

Comment: That's right but doesn't change anything, still the same error. Apparently, both things are not correlated.

Comment: Still the same error doing what? What did you do that has the same error?

Comment: I removed the components array from the parent component, cause the child is global. The thing that you explained to me.

Comment: Are you importing custom-input js components anywhere? the component file needs to be imported or executed somewhere in order to use the component.

Comment: I got all the code inside the index html. I know that isn't good practice, but for now is not a big file.

Comment: That's why you have this error, the scope of `app` stays global, custom elements are supposed to be in that scope and the `child component I created` stays as global because it's not in a file/module scope. I was under the impression that these were separated file but in your case, any global reusable component should be declared as custom, otherwise you are asking vue to look for and imported component like a import/export module method. This is not an error per se, just a bad config structure